# detecting device location through chat bot (dialogflow, twilio, whatsapp)

Tags: geolocation, twilio, dialogflow-es, whatsapp

Hi all i'm developing a whatsapp chat bot from dialog flow, which are integrated by twilio. I want to get device location as a request into dialog flow please help me.

Comment: Is that from Twilio SMS messages or Programmable Chat?

Comment: No no i'm using twilio only for integrating dialog flow with whatsapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio API for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp) doesn't currently support location messages, so you can't currently add this information into Dialogflow. You might want to use your Dialogflow bot to ask for the user to specifically enter an address.

Comment: okay can't we detect the device location using dialog flow in this case as we would have done for google assistant chat bot

Comment: There is no API in WhatsApp at all for getting the user's current location, like there is in the Actions on Google API. To get a location from WhatsApp you will need to have to ask the user for their location.

Comment: Yes. Though note that the Twilio API for WhatsApp does not currently support location share messages, only text and media.

Answer (score 1):

Since the location is just a text link to google-maps 
Like location: https://maps.google.com/?q=lat,long

If you could return this text link in request's body, we could parse it and get latitude & longitude

Comment: sorry i didn't get you can u please ellobarate

Comment: What @BettDoug means is that if you can obtain and parse the Lat-Long from the text message, you can append it to the fixed `Google Maps` search link to obtain the location on the Maps interface.